# returning an undefined variable on php

Tags: php, strategy-pattern

The following code (taken from the following page in portuguese http://br.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html) shows the use of strategy.
My question is how can the load() method from ArrayOutput can return $arrayOfData if it is not defined?

```
interface OutputInterface{
    public function load();
}

class ArrayOutput implements OutputInterface{
    public function load()    {
        return $arrayOfData;
    }
}

class SomeClient{
    private $output;

    public function setOutput(OutputInterface $outputType){
        $this->output = $outputType;
    }

    public function loadOutput(){
        return $this->output->load();
    }
}

$client = new SomeClient();

// Array
$client->setOutput(new ArrayOutput());
$data = $client->loadOutput();
```

Comment: I believe the author made a mistake.  Maybe it was supposed to be $this->arrayOfData. And that property had been set when instantiating the class.

Answer (score 1):

please look at the code below

```
interface OutputInterface{
    public function load();
}

class ArrayOutput implements OutputInterface{
    public function load()    {
        if (empty ($arrayOfData))
        {
           return null;  //if the $arrayOfData is empty then it will return an empty response i.e null
        }
        return $arrayOfData;
    }
}

class SomeClient{
    private $output;

    public function setOutput(OutputInterface $outputType){
        $this->output = $outputType;
    }

    public function loadOutput(){
        return $this->output->load();
    }
}

$client = new SomeClient();

// Array
$client->setOutput(new ArrayOutput());
$data = $client->loadOutput();
```

Answer (score 1):

It cannot. That code there looks more like something to give you an idea about how to implement that pattern. It should be something like:

```
interface OutputInterface {
    public function load();
}

class ArrayOutput implements OutputInterface {

    private $arrayOfData;

    function __construct($array) {
        $this->arrayOfData = $array;
    }

    public function load()    {
        return $this->arrayOfData;
    }
}
```